# How to determine if string is an IP address?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I try to determine if string is ipaddress,

like this:

```
 XElement ipaddresses = new XElement("ipaddresses");
            string[] lines = IpAddress.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var item in lines) {

                IPAddress address;
                if (IPAddress.TryParse(item, out address))
                {

                    switch (address.AddressFamily)
                    {
                        case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
                            // we have IPv4
                            break;
                        case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
                            // we have IPv6
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

So I check it with 9999.

but then it says it is an IP address, and in bij address it shows number: m_ToString = "0.1.134.159"

?? how can that be?

this is the string:  `public string IpAddress { get; set; }`

Thank you

Comment: Well, `9999` is a perfectly valid IP address. Why wouldn't it be? It's not like e.g. `432.2` which is in fact invalid. For example, I get `104.16.103.85` as the IP address of `stackoverflow.com` - this is *exactly* equivallent to an IP address of `1745905493`. The "dot-format" was only really relevant back when it made sense to remember IP addresses (four smaller numbers easier to remember than one big number) and more importantly, it's easier to read common subnet masks (e.g. you know the subnet is 10.* - much harder with the single number; but it only works well with "255-masks"). It stuck.

Comment: So you say it is correct method? I mean so 99999 can be a correct ip address? or: 89999 is correct?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Don't worry about it unless you explicitly want to *force* a dotted format for the IP address (e.g. you expect the user had entered a single number in error).

Comment: Ok, thank you. so this is solved